# Find top 5 using 3 columns by unique values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains 5 columns. I am looking to find the top 5 schools that have the most unique users who liked the school

I was able to get the top 5 schools with likes but I'm struggling to filter to the unique users. I added user_id.nunique() but received an error

```
      df.groupby('school')['like_id'].count().nlargest(5)
```

Sample Data

```
   school_name   Day   user_id  like_id  location_id
   Tilden HS     Mon     1        1          10
   South Shore   Tue     2        2          11
   Tilden HS     Mon     1        3          12
   South Shore   Wed     3        4          13
   Brooklyn      Wed     5        5          14
   Canarsie      Thu     7        6          15
   Erasmus       Fri     8        7          16
   Erasmus       Sat     8        8          17
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
s = df.groupby('school_name')['user_id'].nunique().nlargest(5)
print (s)
school_name
South Shore    2
Brooklyn       1
Canarsie       1
Erasmus        1
Tilden HS      1
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Or if need grouping by combination of columns and get number of unique values by 3 column:

```
s1 = df.groupby(['school_name', 'user_id'])['like_id'].nunique().sum(level=0).nlargest(5)
print (s1)

school_name
Erasmus        2
South Shore    2
Tilden HS      2
Brooklyn       1
Canarsie       1
Name: like_id, dtype: int64
```

---

```
s2 = df.groupby(['school_name', 'like_id'])['user_id'].nunique().sum(level=0).nlargest(5)
print (s2)
school_name
Erasmus        2
South Shore    2
Tilden HS      2
Brooklyn       1
Canarsie       1
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we can pivot:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='school_name', 
               columns='user_id', 
               values='like_id', 
               aggfunc='count',
               fill_value=0)
```

which gives `df_pivot`:

```
user_id      1  2  3  5  7  8
school_name                  
Brooklyn     0  0  0  1  0  0
Canarsie     0  0  0  0  1  0
Erasmus      0  0  0  0  0  2
South Shore  0  1  1  0  0  0
Tilden HS    2  0  0  0  0  0
```

Then, to know max by unique user:

```
df_pivot.ne(0).sum(1).nlargest(5)
```

gives:

```
school_name
South Shore    2
Brooklyn       1
Canarsie       1
Erasmus        1
Tilden HS      1
dtype: int64
```

Or by `like_id`:

```
df_pivot.sum(1).nlargest(5)
```

gives:

```
school_name
Erasmus        2
South Shore    2
Tilden HS      2
Brooklyn       1
Canarsie       1
dtype: int64
```